# Category shows as blur

Tags: magento2, category

Actually, I forgot to create a category in magento 2. But the products are available when I searching. The category shows like the image below I have attached. And it is not in the frontend navigation bar. How to solve this?

[image]

Comment: possibly that product  which you are searching is assigned to other categories as well than kitchen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Maybe you have disabled this category that's why its show you as a blur(disable) just click on  Enable Category toggle button, Yes and Save it to make it visible

Comment: Yes thanks,  its showing now in the frontend. But I want to make that kitchen category as the main category. Because now it is a subcategory. If I do like that is any possible to affect the already uploaded products?

Comment: @Kevin you can do it by just drag your **Kitchen** subcategory and drop into **Default Category**, just make sure SEO url rewrite proper works, go to marketing -> seo and search -> url rewrites and double check from frontend side.